What are finite roots in the context of category theory?
In Lawvere's Elementary Theory of Category of Sets Lawvere uses the term "Finite roots" and says

...in category theory “finite roots” refers to a more general class of operations including
inverse images and intersections and their duals as well as more complicated constructions.

The existence of finite roots, he claims, is implied by Axiom 1 which asserts the existence of products, coproducts, equalizers, and coequalizers.
But I have never heard of "finite roots" outside of this context and can't seem to find anything about the term. What does this mean formally? Is there a more thorough account of what this term means in the context of category theory somewhere?
I suspect that this is the same as finite limits. After all, the existence theorem for limits would imply Axiom 1 means that the category has finite limits and colimits.
But where can I find this characterization in terms of images/intersections/etc.?

As far as I know, the "root" terminology was introduced in Freyd's "Abelian Categories", before "limit" became the standard name for the same thing.

There's an explicit definition of finite roots in Marta Cavallo Bunge's 1966 thesis, which can be found here (pdf link).

A category $\mathcal{X}$ is said to have finite roots iff for every small category such that its set of objects is finite, and letting $\mathcal{A}$ be one such, the functor $\mathcal{X} \to \mathcal{X}^\mathcal{A}$ induced by the functor $\mathcal{A} \to \mathcal{1}$, has both a coadjoint (insuring the existence of left roots) and an adjoint (right finite roots).

In more modern terms, an adjoint is a left adjoint and a coadjoint is a right adjoint. The existence of a left adjoint to the constant diagram functor $\mathcal{X} \to \mathcal{X}^\mathcal{A}$ gives you colimits of diagrams with shape $\mathcal{A}$, while the right adjoint gives limits of the same shape.
So you're correct that finite roots refer to finite limits and finite colimits.

The wording in your quote does not suggest that there's a characterization of finite limits and colimits in terms of images, intersections or such, but rather that those are examples of finite (co)limits. For example, the inverse image is a pullback (along a monomorphism) and intersection is a product (in the category of monomorphisms into an object).
